# Почему не получается объявить несколько структур ошибок в одном файле go?

Tags: golang, goland

Есть два объявленных типа в domain/feedback/Errors.go

```
package feedback

type NotFound struct {
    uuid string
}

func (e NotFound) Error() string {
    return "FeedbackNotFound"
}

type AlreadyExists struct{}

func (e AlreadyExists) Error() string {
    return "FeedbackAlreadyExists"
}
```

После при попытке

```
return false, feedback.AlreadyExists{}
```

Подсвечивается с сообщением `Unresolved type 'AlreadyExists'`
При этом NotFound не подсвечивается и работает хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась за счет разыменования импорта. Название пакета совпало с названием параметра функции